# JavaFX + openjdk-10-jdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, javafx, aws-codebuild

The full story here is that I want to use **AWS Codebuild** to compile a **Java10 + JavaFX** app.

So I made a docker image from the open JDK. [Here](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/0d4a88c802fd2c3d230a71e6e8a4af49295aca5e/10-jdk/Dockerfile) it is.

But looks like it doesn't include JavaFX.
So I installed that too by adding

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y openjfx
```

But still I'm getting errors when I try the build

```
error: module not found: javafx.controls
    requires javafx.controls;
```

if I do `java --list-modules` javafx doesn't show..

Any pointers would be appreciated!

---

!!update!!
so i got a dockerfile to work.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.5
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y libx11-6

RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | \
    debconf-set-selections
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | \
    debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get install -y oracle-java10-installer


RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
```

Comment: You're probably only getting JavaFX 8 using apt-get. You may need to build it yourself: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX

Comment: ok so i got it working.  sure this is horribly inefficient but its my first go at a docker container.. :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this has been running now for a while and seems ok... so i guess i can close the Q.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.5
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y libx11-6

RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | \
    debconf-set-selections
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | \
    debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get install -y oracle-java10-installer


RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
```

Comment: For the time being this seems to be the right way to go. OpenJDK never contained OpenJFX and since Java9 it is also not possible anymore to just add an OpenJFX to an existing OpenJDK installation because these two have to be built together. So, the easiest way is to go with Oracle Java which already contains both. This will however change again with Java11 where even Oracle Java does not contain JavaFX anymore. The plan however is to make JavaFX available separately again then.